# Maven Configuration so that build fails if System.out.println in code

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, system.out

We want to remove all system.out.println from the project.

How to configure the pom or what are the dependencies which are required for the same.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: you may want to search among the available plugins for maven to see if there's one that can help you http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm using maven PMD plugin for the same issue.

1- Add plugin to pom.xml

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${basedir}\src\main\resources\my-rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins
```

2- put my-rules.xml under project resource folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>
    </description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/SystemPrintln" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/AvoidPrintStackTrace"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/OverrideBothEqualsAndHashcode"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/empty.xml/EmptyFinallyBlock"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/ReturnFromFinallyBlock" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/LoggerIsNotStaticFinal"/>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: If you share your configuration I can say something

Comment: I just placed plug in in pom.xml and added rules xml file in project. No change, just used as specified above.

Comment: is it in the correct place ```<ruleset>${basedir}\src\main\resources\my-rules.xml</ruleset>``` also check plugin version .

Comment: Used the version `3.11.0` and placed everything as is.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this personally but take a look at [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/factSheet.html). The Maven plugin can be found [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/).

You could write your own custom detector that searches for `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`. For more information see this site:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-findbug2/

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-module-maven project and got it to work like this.

(1) Add the following plugin to the root/parent pom.xml

```
<build>
      ...
      <plugins>
        ...           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.foo.group</groupId>
                  <artifactId>pmd-rules</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(2) I created a pmd-ruleset.xml (the other config has lots of deprecations)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>
    </description>
    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml/SystemPrintln"/>
    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml/AvoidPrintStackTrace"/>
    <rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml/OverrideBothEqualsAndHashcode"/>
    <rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml/ReturnFromFinallyBlock" />
</ruleset>
```

(3) Created a jar file around it and uploaded it to our repository (like nexus or artifactory). Also created a basic pom.xml

(4) Then I run it with `mvn pmd:pmd pmd:cpd`